# Iterating a function and analysing the result in haskell

Tags: haskell

Ok, referring back to my [previous question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231867/printing-a-result-during-a-recursion-in-haskell) I am still working on learning haskell and solving the current problem of finding the longest chain from the following iteration:

```
 chain n    | n == 0       = error "What are you on about?"
        | n == 1       = [1]
        | rem n 2 == 0 = n : chain (n `div` 2) 
        | otherwise    = n : chain (3 * n + 1)
```

I have this bit sorted, but I need to find the longest chain from a starting number below 1,000,000. So how do I make it do each starting number up to 1,000,000 and then print the one with the longest chain length.
I can do it for one example with:

```
Main> length (chain n)
```

I assume I need the output as an array and then use the `maximum` function to find the value largest chain length and then see how far along it is in the array of answers.

Is this a good way to go about finding a solution or is there a better way (perhaps with better efficiency)?

Comment: project Euler eh? (problem 14)

Comment: You may want to use some dynamic programming for this - let the chain for 10 reuse the already computed chain for 3.  To do this, you'll need to store your results in an intermediate data structure like a Map or an Array - but it will require less processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the `maximum` part. To get the *list* (that's what Haskell's []s are, arrays are different structures) you need to use the `map` higher-order function, like this:

```
chainLength n = length (chain n)

lengths = map chainLength [1..1000000]
```

Essentially, `map` takes as arguments a function and a list. It applies the function to each element in the list and returns the list of the results.

Since you will be needing the number whose chain has that length, you may want change the `chainLength` function to return the number as well, like this:

```
chainLength n = (n, length (chain n))
```

That way you will have an array of pairs, with each number and its chain length.

Now you need to get the pair with the largest second component. That's where the `maximumBy` function comes in. It works just like `maximum` but takes a function as a parameter to select how to compare the values. In this case, the second component of the pair. This comparison function takes two numbers and returns a value of type `Ordering`. This type has only three possible values: `LT`, `EQ`, `GT`, for less than, equal, and greater than, respectively.

So, we need a function that given two pairs tells us how the second components compare to each other:

```
compareSnd (_, y1) (_, y2) = compare y1 y2
-- Or, if you import Data.Function, you can write it like this (thanks alexey_r):
compareSnd = compare `on` snd                  -- reads nicely
```

I used the default `compare` function that compares numbers (well, [not just numbers](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Ord.html#v%3Acompare)).

Now we only need to get the maximum using this function:

```
longestChain = maximumBy compareSnd lengths
```

That gets you a pair of the number with the longest chain and the corresponding length. Feel free to apply `fst` and `snd` as you please.

Note that this could be more much more concisely using `zip` and composition, but since you tagged the question as newbie, I thought it better to break it down like this.

Comment: This worked but how do I find how far along the result array it is?

Comment: I noticed you said *below* 1,000,000 in your question, so feel free to use 999999 instead of 1000000 :)

Comment: I was using `maximumBy` in a wrong way. My Haskell times are long gone, and my memory ain't what it used to be.

Comment: OK, this all works but I get a stack overflow, how do I prevent this happening?
I assume it requires just making an exception or forcing haskell to keep going.

Comment: MaximumBy will cause a stack overflow with large lists. To prevent this from happening, increase the stack size before compilation (with -Ksize, see GHC documentation) or roll your own implementation.

Also, your chain function is not tail-recursive, that will cause a problem (with much-much-much-much bigger numbers).

Comment: OK, after much looking around, I can't figure out to make a compiled program work in haskell. I just get errors complaining it's not for 64 bit windows. I compiled it with:
ghc --make prime.hs

But it won't run, perhaps I'll move to a new question.

Comment: @Jonno: Just checked at the GHC download page: Windows 64bit is not on the supported platform list. Guess you won't get it to compile anytime soon :(.

Comment: Your `compareSnd` is `compare \`on\` snd`.

Comment: @alexey_r: GREAT! Thanks for the tip. I didn't knew about `on`!

Answer (score 1):

SPOILER (solving the problem for positive integers under 100):

```
module Test where
import Data.List   -- this contains maximumBy

chain n
        | n == 0       = error "What are you on about?"
        | n == 1       = [1]
        | rem n 2 == 0 = n : chain (n `div` 2) 
        | otherwise    = n : chain (3 * n + 1)

chains = map (\x -> (x,chain x)) [1..100]

cmpSnd (a,b) (c,d)
       | length b > length d     = GT
       | length b == length d    = EQ
       | otherwise               = LT

solve = (fst . maximumBy cmpSnd) chains
```

The chains function makes use of map. It applies a function to every element of a list of a values, so

```
map succ [1,2]
```

is the same as

```
[succ 1,succ 2]
```

The cmpSnd function is a comparison function that probably exists somewhere deep in the [Hierarchical Libraries](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/), but I could not find it, so I created it. GT means "the first value is greater than the second", the rest is trivial.

Solve takes the maximum (by utilizing the comparison function we defined earlier) of the list. This will be a pair of an integer and a list. It will return the integer only (because of the fst).

A comment: Your chain function is not tail-recursive. This means that large chains will inevitably result in a Stack Overflow. You shall add an explicit accumulator variable and make it tail-recursive.

Comment: Your `compareSnd` is `compare \`on\` (length . snd)`.

Comment: @alexey_r: First of all, thank you :)! The libraries are huge, I am a Haskeller since 2006, and I never encountered "on". Your definition is points-free, however, the type of cmpSnd is more general than your function's. This type of generality is unnecessary for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
fst $ maximumBy (length . snd) $ zip [1..1000000] $ map chain [1..1000000]
```

(untested)

i.e. don't work out how far along the longest chain is in the list of longest chains, but carry around the seed values with the chains instead.

Comment: The first projection is called `fst`, not `first` :)

Answer (score 0):

I studied Haskell years ago, so I don't remember it that well. On the other hand I've tested this code and it works. You will get the max chain and the number that generates it. But as fiships has stated before, it will overflow for big values.

```
chain :: Int -> [Int]
chain n
    | n == 0 = []
    | n == 1 = [1]
    | rem n 2 == 0 = n : chain (n `div` 2) 
    | otherwise = n : chain (3 * n + 1)

length_chain :: Int -> Int
length_chain n = length (chain n)

max_pos :: (Int,Int) -> Int -> [Int] -> (Int,Int)
max_pos (m,p) _ [] = (m,p)
max_pos (m,p) a (x:xs)
    | x > m = max_pos (x,a) (a+1) xs
    | otherwise = max_pos (m,p) (a+1) xs
```

The instruction will be

```
Main> max_pos (0,0) 1 (map length_chain [1..10000])
(262,6171)
```